# Connect to External SQL Database in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, .net

I've got an SQL server and database setup on an external server (let's call the domain name "hello.com" for the purposes of this), and I want to connect to this server via a C# program. So far I have this (All server/database details are different to the real ones):

```
private static void SetupSQL()
{
    string connectionString = "server=hello.com; database=db1; uid=user1; pwd=xxxxx;";
    connection = new SqlConnection();
    connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Connected");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message.ToString());
    }
}
```

This is giving me an error message:

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
```

I have checked all the connection string, and I am allowed remote access, as I have SQLWorkbench open querying the database right now on the same computer.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why is this tagged as mysql if the database is sql server?

Comment: check your sqlInstance with the name in connectionString

Comment: It's a MySQL Server. Sorry if I didn't make that clear.

Comment: Have you read this: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/ ? **Edit**: No, it's not clear since a [**`SqlConnection`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx) is clearly a **SQL-Server** connection.

Comment: does SQL SERVER Status is Running?
Read This Article [Here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/) if you are using MySQL you should Install [MySQL Connector](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/).

Comment: Have you worked through this checklist: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2007/03/31/named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server.aspx Actually this one is a bit better: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/ I'm looking at point 2 in your case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need the `MySQL` driver:

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

You can then use the the `MySqlConnection` connection class to connect.

```
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
```

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43438/Connect-C-to-MySQL

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `SqlConnection` object to connect to MySQL database, you should use `MySqlConnection` instead after you import its dll